# Initialize a multidimensional array as a class Member in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class, let' say:

```
class Foo
{
    public:

         unsigned int Index;
         float Size;
         Foo(const unsigned int index);
         ~Foo();

    private:
         int Children[2][2];

};
```

And I want to initialize the Children parameter in the constructor:

```
Foo::Foo(const unsigned int index) : Index(index)
{
    this->Size = 0.5 / index;
    this->Children = {};

    if (index < MAX_DIVS) {
        for (int _x = 0; _x < 2; _x++) {
            for (int _y = 0; _y < 2; _y++) {
                this->Children[_x][_y] = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

I can assign the initial value to `Size` doing `this->Size= 0.5/Index`, but I cannot initialize Children;
Visual Studio gives me an error on `this->Children = {}` saying: "Expression must have a modifiable lvalue". Why is it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `this->Children = {};`? It seems unnecessary since you override the values afterward anyway?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am trying to initialize it as VIsual Studio tells me that the operator Foo::Foo does not initialize Foo::Children

Comment: Fix your indentation first.  You can't assign to an array, nor can you traverse a two-dimensional array with three indexes.

Comment: @L.F. I'm am so sorry, I had edited the code to post it, making it a bit simpler, the array was initially 3D, I'll fix the code now.

Comment: If you want to initialize an array you should either have a default value in the class declaration or use the member initializer list (like you already do for `Index`. In fact your entire constructor could be simplified to: `Foo::Foo(const unsigned int index) : Index(index), Children(), Size(0.5/index) {}`

Comment: @UnholySheep by doing this, my array will be an empty one, right?

Comment: If by "empty" you mean "all elements will be 0" then yes

Comment: @Fabrizio Arrays have fixed size, so value-initializing an array value-initializes all its elements, resulting in an all-zero array.

Comment: @L.F. ok, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @L.F. and @UnholySheep pointed out, to have a default value for the `Children` Variable, it should be added to the member initializer list, like this:

```
Foo::Foo(const unsigned int index) : Index(index), Children(), Size(0.5/index) {}
```

This will initialize the variable Children as an all 0 array which can be then further modified in the constructor.